# App stops when implementing ConnectivityManager and NetworkInfo

Tags: java, android

For my app, I was trying to detect when the user is connected to the internet. This is one of the methods I've been using, although I've used some other that where basically the same, but using other methods of the objects used:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected())
{
  return true;
}
  return false;
}
```

Even if this does not lead to any compilation error, when launching the app it stops abruptly and does not respond. I'd like to know why this happens and how to solve it or, if has no aparent solution, if there's another way of doing what I wanted.

I have tried deleting part of the code strategically and I have noticed that the part that gives problems is `netInfo`with both of ways it is being used, but I don`t know why.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking for the permission? ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission. Remember starting from api 23 permissions most be declared in manifest and ask in real time. Also, try with other device or emulator, and restart Android Studio, you have to have console logs.

Comment: I´ve tried with two emulators and both gave me the same result. As for the permission, I've added it but it keeps failing.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Access Network Permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE) in [AndroidManifest](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicContactables/AndroidManifest.html) file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I've added that line, but now, even if the app opens, it stays in a white page.

Comment: @pepito that will be some another issue.

Answer (score 0):

First add `users-permission` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file like this

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Second, this pics of code can give you a `boolean`. Network connection is available or not. so put it in a method and get return of those code like this..

```
public boolean getCheckedNetStatus(Context context) {
   try{
      ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
         return true;
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("Net Check Err", e.toString());
     return false;
   }
}
```

Have try catch will protect your from unexpected crash your app...

Now Call it to conditionally execute your certain action like this

```
if(getCheckedNetStatus(yourActivity.this)){
    //Net is available 
    //So do your action
}else{
   //Net not available 
   //you can notify user that net not available 
   //So you (User) can't do this
}
```

Comment: As I said previously, the permission is already added. Refering to the exception, I've added the try-catch as suggested, but the white screen keeps appearing.

Comment: White screen appearing means? Is there any Exception?

Comment: I mean that when I play the app in the emulator it doesn't work and the screen remains white. It seems like there are no exceptions.

Comment: What you trying to do on Network condition? Can you share your code?

Comment: I am planning to display an alert dialogue, but I haven´t done anything yet because I am trying to solve this before adding full functionatility.

Comment: If your computer have no internet connection then your emulator will return false by getCheckedNetStatus() method. What it returning in you case..

Comment: Hi... do you get solution?